# how to install docker on the Github codespaces by default?

Tags: docker, github-codespaces

I am using this repository to install php7.4 as default version in my codespace.
https://github.com/jimblizzard/codespaces-for-php-demo

it was successful. but I want to have docker engine inside my codespace to hast some third party application beside my codes. I tried to install a docker engine using the provided documentation in docker's website but it seems adding new gpg repositories is banned because of security.

how can I configure my codespaces to have docker by default?